# Using Django ORM to Delete Records with 0 items

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following table structures:

```
class Tags:
    name = fields.CharField(max_length=100)
    ref     = models.ManyToManyField(RefTags)

class RefTags
    foo = varchar(128)
    tag = models.ForeignKey('Tag')
```

How can I do a delete from Tags if there are no associated records in RefTags?

Thanks

Edit:  I figured it out, it was really easy:

Tag.objects.filter(ref__isnull=True).delete()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like

```
for tag in Tags.objects.all():
    if tag not in RefTags.objects.all():
        RefTags.objects.filter(tag=tag).delete()
```

It probably would be more efficient to put RegTags.objects.all() in a list, cycle through it and then do the deletion.

Answer (score 0):

```
from models import Tags

Tags.objects.filter(...).delete()
Tags.objects.all().delete()
```

etc...

Depending on what exactly you want to delete.

Comment: How would I just do a select on that criteria?  From there I can do the delete   :-)

Comment: Ok, I see you figured it out. Didn't really get in your original question what criteria you meant. Now I see. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the money:

Tag.objects.filter(ref__isnull=True).delete()